# How to identify the immediate tag using preceding

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple checkbox to click, but I want to click the immediate checkbox near the tag "Platinum card". Currently the below `xpath` clicks the first checkbox which is not next to Platinum card

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Platinum Card')]//preceding::input[@type='checkbox']")
```

Comment: good to have html code..

Comment: formatting done + I capitalized every where. But still you need to write a code snippet, so that users can verify accurately and you will get useful answers.

Comment: Sure sir. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following: Which will return the first input element

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Platinum Card')]//preceding::input[1]")
```